# Allow only Negative number in CXGrid

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

Im working in Delphi 2006 with devexpress.

I have a cxGrid. I want to restrict the entry of values for a negative number column,

my probleme is how can I test the position of '-' when adding it the cell

Is some simple way to allow only negative number in the cell of cxgrid.

thanks in advance

Comment: The "normal" way in DevEx controls is to write an `OnValidate` handler.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i did it in presskey and onkeydown but when I want to have the content of the cell when editing it in order to test  the position if I have the '-' or not  there are some example to do it ?

Comment: I suggest going to the DevEx support site and searching for OnValidate there. Their support is quite good.

Comment: how can I get the string value in onpresskey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eaiest way to do what you want is to use a MaskEdit in the grid cell, but as you've said in a comment that you'd prefer not to use one, I've moved how to do that to the end of this answer.

You and control the user's editing of the cell text entirely in your own code, and I'll show you how to do that.

By default, if you type a letter key into an cxGrid column for an integer field, you hear a beep.  That happens as a result of the key causing `TField.IsValidChar(InputChar: Char)` for the Integer field linked to the cell to return `False`.

If you want to deal with "wrong" keys like that yourself, without using a MaskEdit, you can do it in the EditKeyPressed event.  The code below shows that you can do your own enforcement of what the user can enter in the field without having to resort to simulating editing-key presses like you quoted in a comment below.  Please note the comments in the code carefully.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1EditKeyPress(Sender:
    TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; AEdit:
    TcxCustomEdit; var Key: Char);
var
  AField : TField;
  strValue : String;
  V : Variant;
  i,
  InsertPoint,
  EC : Integer;

  function CharIsOK(Ch : Char) : Boolean;
  begin
    Result := CharInSet(Ch, ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                        '7', '8', '9', '-', '+']);
    // Or Result := Ch in ['0', ... for Delphi prior to D2009
  end;

begin
  if AItem = cxGrid1DBTableView1Value then begin
    //  The following manually cleans up input into a TIntegerField column
    // whose Properties is set to TextEdit

    // First, pick up the text in the inplace editor
    V := AEdit.EditingValue;
    if not VarIsNull(V) then
      strValue := AEdit.EditingValue
    else
      strValue := '';

    if strValue <> '' then begin
      //  Next, check that the Key is a valid one for an Integer field.
      if CharIsOk(Key) then begin
      //  The fact that the Key is a valid character for an Integer field
      //  does not in itself guarantee that the entire editing string, including the Key
      //  which is about to be added to in, is a valid string representation of an integer,
      //  e.g. it might be '--', '+1-5', etc
      //  So, we add the Key to the existing editing string and see if it converts to an integer
      //  Of course, there is the wrinkle that the caret may not be at the end of the editing text
      //  so we need to find out where the caret is.  First we need 
      //  to check that AEdit is a TcxtextEdit so that we can access
      // its SelStart property
        Assert(AEdit is TcxTextEdit);
        InsertPoint := TcxTextEdit(AEdit).SelStart;
        Insert(Key, strValue, InsertPoint + 1);
        Val(strValue, i, EC);
        //  if EC is non-zero, the conversion failed, so we suppress the Key
        if EC <> 0 then
          Key := Chr(0);
       end
       else
         //  the Key might be a backspace, so permit that
         if Ord(Key) <> VK_Back then
           Key := Chr(0);
    end
  end;
end;
```

Of course, if you actually want to achieve what you state in the title of your q, namely only allow negative numbers, you can make a trivial change to this code to require that the editing text starts with a minus sign (and the editing text + Key converts to an integer if the editing text is not empty).

Btw, this code answers your query "how can I get the string value in onpresskey ?" of course.

To use a MaskEdit in the cxGrid cell, select the cxGrid column in the Object Inspector, then

- Go to its Properties entry in the OI
- Select Mask Edit from the drop-down list
- Set the edit mask for a negative number.  See the Online Help if you need help to do this: basically, you enter a minus sign followed by a number of 9s.

Then, the user can only enter a negative number and can't edit out the leading minus sign.

Comment: The problem that the cxGrid is connected to a datasource then  I can't use this property to change to MaskEdit

Comment: Well, mine is connected to a TDataSource too, and I didn't have any difficulty change the Properties to Mask Edit when I tested my answer!  What can't you do, what are the symptoms?

Comment: ok  I done the maskEdit but what can I put in the Edit mask to have  for example "-123' and "123"

Comment: Edit masks are explained the OLH.  In any case, I thought you were trying to avoid the user entering '123' without a preceding minus sign.

Comment: In fact I want to  accept positve and negative number

Comment: Then why did you say "Is some simple way to allow **only** negative number in the cell of cxgrid." in your question?

Comment: I didn't think that I wll use Mask Edit that s why I ask simply for negative number, I think that I will use OnPresskey

Comment: See the update to my answer.  If that still doesn't do what you want, you really do need to explain more clearly exactly what you *do* want.

Comment: `begin
    strValue := AEdit.EditingValue;
    if not (Key in [VK_BACK,VK_SUBTRACT, Ord(0)..Ord(9), Ord(DecimalSeparator)]) then
      key := VK_BACK
    else
    if ((Key = Ord(DecimalSeparator)) or (Key = VK_SUBTRACT)) and (Pos('-', strValue) > 0) then
       key := VK_BACK
    else if  (Pos('-', strValue) <> 1) then
       key := VK_BACK ;
  end;          `    but When testing if I put a wrong key then with the instruction VK_BaCK it must delete the last key added where isn't the case

Comment: Define what you mean by a "wrong key"; I've no idea what you're trying to achieve with that code, so I'm not surprised it is evidently not working as you wish.  What you want should be clearly stated **in your question**, not in a comment to an answer to it.

Comment: Ah, CharInSet was an addition when they added Unicode support in D2009, I think.  Instead of that, you could use the traditional "Ch in ['0'..'9', ..." etc.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi MartynA thanks for the code, just one qustion I didnt found CharInSet in delphi 2006  , But I do another way thank youu that s what I want :)

Comment: Thanks a lot MartynA  that's all what I need :)